# My menu that uses the nav tag doesn't fit across the page fully and only goes across half of the screen

Tags: html, css

When in the mobile screen size, my menu bar doesn't stretch across the entire page and only covers half of it despite me using css grid and formatting it correctly. Once you click on the menu button, it also doesn't display the nav areas correctly as some of the options are off the screen.

I have tried adding overflow: hidden into my nav in the css however this hasn't fixed the problem at all and it still only sits on one side of the page.

CSS:

```
.grid {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
grid-template-rows: 10vh 5vh 12vh 5vh 58vh 10vh;
/*grid-gap: 6px; */
grid-template-areas:
"header  header"
"menu    menu"
"intro   intro"
"figure   figure"
"content content"
"footer  footer";
}

nav {
grid-area: menu;
display: none;
clear: both;
justify-content: center;
background: black;
flex-direction: column;
}

nav a {
padding: 1.25em 1.5em;
color: white;
background: darkred;
text-decoration: none;
transition: all 1.5s;
border-right: 1px solid white;
border-left: 1px solid white;
}  

.menu {
background: darkred;
text-align: center;
color: white;
line-height: 2em;
} 

.menu-toggle {
display: flex;
}
```

HTML:

```
<body class="grid">
<div class="menu" id="menu-toggle">MENU</div>
<nav id="menu-nav">
<a href="index.html">HOME</a>
<a href="news.html">NEWS</a>
<a href="teamhistory.html">TEAM HISTORY</a>
<a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a>
</nav>
```

When in mobile screen for the menu bar to stretch across the page but the actual output is that it covers half the screen width.

Answer (score 0):

that is because you have created a menu with two columns and put everything in the left column which is the reason it takes 50% of the screen. You need to have nested grids in order to achieve

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}
.menu {
  width: 100%;
  background: darkred;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  line-height: 2em;
}
#menu-nav {
  width: 100%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  /*grid-gap: 6px; */
}

nav a {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  background: darkred;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>temp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="temp.css" />
  </head>

  <body class="grid">
    <div class="menu" id="menu-toggle">MENU</div>
    <nav id="menu-nav">
      <a href="index.html">HOME</a> <a href="news.html">NEWS</a>
      <a href="teamhistory.html">TEAM HISTORY</a>
      <a href="gallery.html">GALLERY</a>
    </nav>

    <script src="temp.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but if I did, I think you should use width property from css and change it for the element that you want to cover all the width of the page.

```
width: 100%;
```

Comment: If it is not what you mean, I would be glad to hear the correct thing from you.